# Prove that in a ring with $x^3 = x$ we have $x+x+x+x+x+x=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

This was an exercise on a course on abstract algebra at the University of Groningen. I have been working on this for ages, but I can't seem to figure it out.

## Problem

Let $R$ be a ring with $\forall x \in R: x^3 = x$.  Prove that $x+x+x+x+x+x=0$.

## Tried

If $x=0$, the statement is of course trivial.

If $x \neq 0$, we have $x(x^2-1)=0=(x^2-1)x$, so either $x^2 = 1$, so $x$ is a unit, or $x^2-1$ and $x$ are zero-divisors.

And this is as far as I get... Any help would be appreciated! :)

## Edit: guide to answer

The following hint was provided by Abel:

$$\begin{align}
x \in R &\implies x+x \in R\\
&\implies x+x=(x+x)^3
\end{align}$$

If you then work out all the terms, the answer will follow quickly.

Comment: Hint: let $\rm\ x = 2z = z + z$

Comment: Hint: try $x+x = (x+x)^3 = ...$.

Comment: @Abel: Very nice! Why not post that as an answer? [Or, rather, undelete your answer.]

Comment: Since it's classified as homework I figured an answer is not really appropriate...

Comment: @Abel: Thank you! Works like a charm. I'll add it in an edit for future reference. :)

Comment: Happy to help a fellow RuG student

Comment: @Abel What Clive meant is that your answer should be that hint.

Comment: @Git Gud Ah, I'll keep that in mind. Should I still post it (for future reference as Eric put it)?

Comment: @Abel Yes, definitely.This question shouldn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: @Abel Yeah, hints are way better in this context. Especially since I have an exam monday. xD But you're also from the RuG? I must know you then. :)

Comment: @Abel As GitGud says, I did mean to post the hint as an answer; see also [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138/19542) and [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148/19542). Answers don't have to be (and often shouldn't be) full solutions; you gave a decent hint and I think it would be fine posted as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try $x+x = (x+x)^3$ and expand the latter.

Answer (score 2):

When examining the consequences of an identity in an algebra, the natural place to start is the ground, i.e. the ground terms generated by evaluating the identity at the *constants* of the algebra. For rings we have constants $0$ and $1$ so its natural to look first at what the identity implies in the subring generated by these constants. In our example, we have the identity $\rm\ f(x) = x^3\!-x = 0,\ $ so we deduce that $\rm\:f(0)=0,\ f(1)=0,\ \color{#C00}{f(2) = 6},\ f(3) = 24,\,\ldots$ are all zero. Thus $\rm\:\color{#C00}6 = 0\:\Rightarrow\:6x = 0.\:$

The proof generalizes to  rings without $1$, simply evaluate $\rm\:f\:$ at $\rm\:\color{#C00}{2x} = x\!+\!x\:$ instead of at $\rm\:\color{#C00}2.\:$ In fact we can deduce further identities using polynomial arithmetic on the identities. For example, we easily infer $\rm\: 0 = f(x\!+\!1)-f(x) = 3\,(x^2\!+\!x).\:$ More generally we can compute gcds/resultants of $\rm\:f(x\!+\!n),\,f(x),\:$ and perform more complex eliminations using multivariate generalizations of the Euclidean algorithm (e.g. Grobner bases). These techniques come in handy when attacking more difficult problems, e.g. Jacobson's commutativity theorem: $\rm\: x^{n} = x\:\Rightarrow\:xy = yx$.